# Adicionar mirror/espelho de repositório Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: linux

Qual a forma de incluir o http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ na minha sources.list do Debian 9 (Stretch)?

Eu preciso incluir com o `contrib non-free` também.

Eu preciso que seja explicado o porquê também, pois as URLs da sources.list (/etc/apt/sources.list) não são nada iguais às do espelho FTP online.

Exemplo:

**URL:** `http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/non-free/`

**sources.list** [Não está certo, só um exemplo mesmo]: `deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/stretch stretch main contrib non-free`

Qual a forma correta de incluir o espelho brasileiro do Debian 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui achar [**neste link**](https://linuxdicasesuporte.blogspot.com.br/2017/06/sourceslist-debian-stretch.html).

`deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free`

O que é quase igual ao que eu havia postado na pergunta, mudando somente a primeira palavra `stretch` para `debian`.